# How to match sum of two or more objects?

Tags: pattern-matching, sequence

I am trying to match expressions that are the sum of two or more objects with a specific head. However I can not get this work properly.

For example

```
obj[a]+obj[b] /. Plus[A:Repeated[_obj,{2,Infinity}] :> Hold[A]
```

returns

```
obj[a]+obj[b]
```

instead of

```
Hold[obj[a]+obj[b]]
```

as desired.

Somewhat confusingly allowing single repeats

```
obj[a]+obj[b] /. Plus[A:Repeated[_obj,{1,Infinity}] :> Hold[A]
```

does return

```
Hold[obj[a]]+Hold[obj[b]]
```

as expected. Also using a different overall head instead of "Plus" for example "List" also works

```
List[obj[a],obj[b]] /. List[A:Repeated[_obj,{2,Infinity}] :> Hold[A]
```

returns

```
Hold[obj[a],obj[b]]
```

Does anybody have an idea what is going on here (and how to achieve what I was trying in the first place)?

Comment: `Plus` on the left-hand-side of the rule evaluates, which changes your pattern.  Try `obj[a] + obj[b] /. Verbatim[Plus][A : Repeated[_obj, {2, Infinity}]] :> Hold[A]` instead.  This question is a duplicate and I shall mark it as such in a minute.

Comment: If anyone has a suggestion for a better duplicate please comment or flag.